# How to use ng-if and ng-blur together?

Tags: angularjs

```
 <input kendo-time-picker
        name="ArriveDateTime"
        class="form-control"
        k-format="'hh:mm tt'"
        k-parse-formats="['hh:mm tt']"
        k-ng-model="technician.ArriveDateTime"
        k-ng-disabled="!technician.IsLocked"
        ng-blur="Actions.OnChangeTime()"/>
```

I want to use `ng-blur` on specific conditions.
I have added variable in controller named as `$scope.Variables.isFormSubmitted` which may be true or false.I want to call action on blur only if `$scope.FormSubmitted` is true.
So how can I check the condition first and then use `ng-blur`?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite the expression like this:

```
ng-blur="Variables.isFormSubmitted && Actions.OnChangeTime()"
```

Answer (score 1):

Include condition inside `ng-blur`

```
ng-blur="Variables.isFormSubmitted ? Actions.OnChangeTime(): doSomethingElseOr keepEmpty()"
```